# Given an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, is it possible to express $U$ as a disjoint union of $(a,b)$'s where $a,b \in Q$ for some dense set $Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, dense-subspaces

I am aware that any open subset $U \in \mathbb{R}$ may be expressed as a countable disjoint union of open intervals.

Now, if we are given a dense subset $Q \subset \mathbb{R}$, is it possible to express
\begin{equation}
U=\cup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i)
\end{equation}
where $a_i,b_i \in Q$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and the union $\cup_{i=1}^\infty$ is disjoint.

I guess this is true, but not sure how to verify rigorously.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Why do you think it's true? The set $Q=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$. How would you express the open set $U=(0,1)$ as a disjoint union of open intervals with endpoints in $Q$? Another example: what if $U=Q=\mathbb R$?

Comment: @user14111  I see.. OK, I guess I have to drop the condition "disjoint". Then, it looks true.

Comment: Right! The set of open intervals with endpoints in $Q$ (any dense subset of $\mathbb R$) is a *base* for the topology of $\mathbb R$. On the other hand, the decomposition of an open set $U$ into **disjoint** open intercals is **unique**, the open intervals (one or two of which might be infinite intervals) are the connected components of $U$, you don't get to pick the endpoints.

Comment: @user14111 Thank you. My actual question is the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778528/if-int-t-1t-2-f-nt-dt-has-a-limit-as-n-to-infty-for-dense-points I would appreciate if you help me once more..