# If $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f_n(t) dt$ has a limit as $n \to \infty$ for dense points $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, limit exists for all finite intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of non-negative locally-integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Further suppose that there exists a dense subset $Q \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f_n(t)dt
\end{equation}
converges to a finite limit as $n \to \infty$ for any pair $(t_1,t_2) \in Q^2$.

Then, my question is that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, does the sequence
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f_n(t)dt
\end{equation}
converges to a finite limit as $n \to \infty$?

I suspect that this is true since $f_n$'s are assumed to be nonnegative, but cannot justify easily.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Try considering for example $Q=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and functions whose support alternates between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$, and gets "squeezed" towards $0$.

Comment: @MW Taking $f_n(x)=\boldsymbol{1}_{0<x<1/n}\,n$ when $n$ is even and $f_n(x)=\boldsymbol{1}_{-1/n<x<0}\,n$ when $n$ is odd for instance, the integral converges to $2$ when $a<0<b$, to $0$ when $0<a<b$ or $a<b<0$, but doesn't converge when $a=0<b$ or $a<b=0$.

Comment: @WillowWisp yeah I realized it and deleted my comment, but not quite in time I guess:)

Comment: @WillowWisp Thank you for your ingenious counterexample. If I assume instead that $\int^{a}_{t_0} f(t) dt$ has a finite limit for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t_0 \in Q$, then can I possibly get the desired answer? Could you please help me once more?

Comment: @Keith In that case yes, since we can write $\int_a^b f_n(x) dx = \int_a^{t_0} f_n(x) dx + \int_{t_0}^b f_n(x) dx = - \int_{t_0}^a f_n(x) dx + \int_{t_0}^b f_n(x) dx$.